# How To Select One Top Of Each Record By Id in Second Joined Table In SQL Server SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, left-join

This is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   E.EquipmentId, E.Name, E.KakhdaryNo, E.PropertyNo, 
   E.InstallationPlace, E.InstallationDate, E.BuyDate,
   Vt.TypeCaption, E.VisitChosen, E.LastVisitDate, V.VisitReport
FROM 
   TblEquipment E 
LEFT JOIN 
   TblVisitType Vt ON E.VisitType = Vt.VisitTypeId 
LEFT JOIN 
   TblVisit V ON E.EquipmentId = V.EquipmentId 
WHERE 
   1=1 
   AND E.Deleted <> 'True'
GROUP BY 
   E.Name
```

I get an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'TblEquipment.EquipmentId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I do not use group by the result shown like this:

[image: This is result]

So as you can see Equipment ID 15 is duplicate.. and I just want one of those.. I prefer the top one, I mean newer record

Please help me how to do this?

Comment: Picture is not clear, Please add some `sample data` and `expected output`. You are `selecting` bunch of `non aggregated column's` and keeping only one in `group by` which is not allowed in `Sql Server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aa you are using Group By clause so you have to use Aggregate function
>   for each selecting column or you have to use the column in Group By
>   clause

e.g

```
select a,b,max(c),min(d) from  table_Name group by a,b
```

in your case

```
SELECT 
Max(E.EquipmentId),
E.Name,
Max(E.KakhdaryNo),
Max(E.PropertyNo),
Max(E.InstallationPlace),
Max(E.InstallationDate),
Max(E.BuyDate),
Max(Vt.TypeCaption),
Max(E.VisitChosen),
Max(E.LastVisitDate),
Max(V.VisitReport)
FROM 
TblEquipment E 
LEFT JOIN 
TblVisitType Vt 
on
 E.VisitType=Vt.VisitTypeId 
LEFT JOIN 
TblVisit V 
on 
E.EquipmentId=V.EquipmentId 
WHERE 1=1 AND E.Deleted <> 'True'
Group BY E.Name`
```

Comment: It become True...can you please describe me why?

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in comment you are selecting bunch of `non aggregated column's` and keeping only one in `group by` which is not allowed in `Sql Server`. To remove the duplicate rows use the `row_number` window function.

Also remove `1=1` condition in `where` clause which is not needed.

If am not wrong this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT EquipmentId,
       NAME,
       KakhdaryNo,
       PropertyNo,
       InstallationPlace,
       InstallationDate,
       BuyDate,
       .TypeCaption,
       VisitChosen,
       LastVisitDate,
       VisitReport
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY E.EquipmentId ORDER BY order_by_column) AS RN,
               E.EquipmentId,
               E.NAME,
               E.KakhdaryNo,
               E.PropertyNo,
               E.InstallationPlace,
               E.InstallationDate,
               E.BuyDate,
               Vt.TypeCaption,
               E.VisitChosen,
               E.LastVisitDate,
               V.VisitReport
        FROM   TblEquipment E
               LEFT JOIN TblVisitType Vt
                      ON E.VisitType = Vt.VisitTypeId
               LEFT JOIN TblVisit V
                      ON E.EquipmentId = V.EquipmentId
        WHERE  E.Deleted <> 'True') A
WHERE  RN = 1
```

Comment: i got this error: Invalid column name 'order_by_column'

Comment: @user1998368 - For example i kept that name. You need to use the one of the existing column in which you need to find `top 1`